# Reject parameters in a function that have specific type in a prop

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I have a component that is prepaired to receive a parameter called **type** that can be one of four options email, mobileNumber, cep, password'. If the **property type value** is **password** the properties icon and onPressIcon should'nt be parsed. I have typed this props as follow:

```
type TextInputT = {
  type: 'email' | 'mobileNumber' | 'cep' | 'password';
  name: string;
  label: string;
  onPressIcon: () => void;
  icon: string;
};
```

How can I do to make the props **icon** and **onPressIcon** invalid if the type of textinput is password?

I already tried

```
type TextInput = {
  type: 'password';
  name: string;
  label: string;
};

type CustomTextInput = {
  type: 'email' | 'mobileNumber' | 'cep';
  name: string;
  label: string;
  onPressIcon: () => void;
  icon: string;
};

export type TextInputT = TextInput | CustomTextInput;
```

But in component props type asignment throw the errors as follow

[image]

EDIT1: My TextInput.tsx

```
const TextInput: React.FC<TextInputT> = ({
  type,
  name,
  label,
  onPressIcon,
  icon,
}) => {
  const inputValueRef = React.useRef(null);

  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [valueShown, setValueShown] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(name);

  const hasError: boolean = meta.touched && typeof meta.error !== 'undefined';
  const error: string = meta.touched && meta.error;

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content
        active={isFocused}
        error={hasError}
        disabled={false}
        onPress={() => inputValueRef?.current?.focus()}
        activeOpacity={1}>
        {(isFocused || meta.touched) && (
          <Label active={isFocused} error={hasError} disabled={false}>
            {label}
          </Label>
        )}
        <InputBox>
          <InputValue
            ref={inputValueRef}
            secureTextEntry={type === 'password' && !valueShown}
            onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
            placeholder={!isFocused ? label : ''}
            value={getFormattedValue({
              value: field.value,
              mask: type,
            })}
            onChangeText={field.onChange(name)}
            onBlur={() => [setIsFocused(false), helpers.setTouched(true)]}
          />
          {type === 'password' && (
            <IconBox onPress={() => setValueShown(!valueShown)}>
              <IconDynamic
                name={`${valueShown ? 'EyeClosed' : 'Eye'}`}
                width={24}
                height={24}
                fill={colors.C.default}
              />
            </IconBox>
          )}
          {icon && onPressIcon && (
            <IconBox onPress={onPressIcon}>
              <IconDynamic
                name={icon}
                width={24}
                height={24}
                fill={colors.C.default}
              />
            </IconBox>
          )}
        </InputBox>
      </Content>
      {hasError && (
        <ErrorBox>
          <TextError>{error}</TextError>
        </ErrorBox>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```

Comment: [Please replace or supplement images of code or errors with plain text versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)  Also, please consider providing a [mcve] that demonstrates your errors when used with a standalone IDE.  My suggestion would look like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6zVN), but without use case examples it's hard to tell if that works or if you would run into other problems.  Reproducible examples help you get a good answer quicker.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The safer option for TS is to disallow using `onPressIcon` until you check the `type` property.

```js
type TextInput = {
  type: 'password';
  name: string;
  label: string;
};

type CustomTextInput = {
  type: 'email' | 'mobileNumber' | 'cep';
  name: string;
  label: string;
  onPressIcon: () => void;
  icon: string;
};

export type Union = TextInput | CustomTextInput;

const comp=(prop:Union)=>{
    if(prop.type==='password'){
        const x = prop.onPressIcon // error
    }
    if(prop.type==='email'){
        const x = prop.onPressIcon // ok
    }
}
```

To understand it better, see next example:

```js
type TextInput = {
  type: 'password';
  name: string;
  label: string;
};

type CustomTextInput = {
  type: 'email' | 'mobileNumber' | 'cep';
  name: string;
  label: string;
  onPressIcon: () => void;
  icon: string;
};

export type Union = TextInput | CustomTextInput;

type Keys = keyof Union // "type" | "name" | "label" < ------ only properties which are common for both type
```

Imagine that TS allows you to get `onPressIcon` property without checking `type` property.

It will break whole idea of unions.

Comment: Awesome, now is crearly the concept of union in this case but I still confused about how to invalidade icon and onPressIcon if the type is password :(

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros I'm not sure what do you mean `invalidate`. COuld you please provide an example?